# Web scraping is not getting links in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am going to scrape all links of product and details of each product.
If I use vpn, it's opening product list. But it's not working if I use normal browser or proxy.
So far, I tried below code, but no result.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time as t
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")
chrome_options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable");

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"])

# proxy = "141.11.32.229:50100"
proxy = "198.59.191.234:8080"
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = proxy
prox.socks_proxy = proxy
prox.ssl_proxy = proxy
prox.socks_version = 5

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

def get_target_links():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                               options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    url = "https://www.target.com/c/makeup-beauty/-/N-5xu1e?Nao=0&moveTo=product-list-grid"
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler"))).click()
        print('declined cookies')
    except Exception as e:
        print('no cookie button!')
    t.sleep(2)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="dialog dialog-email"]'))).find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="icon close"]').click()
        print('dismissed 10% offer')
    except Exception as e:
        print('no 10% offer, damn')
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="dialog dialog-country"]'))).find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="icon close"]').click()
        print('dismissed country popup')
    except Exception as e:
        print('no country popup')
    print('fjdkfjdkfjd')
    time.sleep(10)
    page_source = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
    product_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="styles__ProductCardItemInfoDiv-sc-h3r0um-0 jvDPEP")
    print(len(product_divs))
    for pro in product_divs:
        link = pro.find("a")['href']
        print(link)
    print("product_divs", product_divs)
    links = [link["href"] for link in product_divs]
    print(links)
    print(len(links))

    return links

get_target_links()
```

As I know, the website doesn't give permission to our region.
Could someone help me to solve this issue. I bought proxy but it is not working too

Answer (score 0):

When you load a site you want to scrape, always inspect what it loads with the [network monitor](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/). In this case you see that it loads the data dynamically from an api. This means that you can skip scraping altogether and load the data directly from the api into pandas:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://redsky.target.com/redsky_aggregations/v1/web_platform/product_summary_with_fulfillment_v1?key=9f36aeafbe60771e321a7cc95a78140772ab3e96&tcins=17088329%2C16867574%2C83773151%2C80160207%2C82172707%2C49112784%2C11658423%2C75563573%2C83773154%2C80114917%2C13586156%2C83721872%2C11127801%2C77281643%2C84044937%2C14582476%2C52117575%2C82247992%2C13081077%2C76485900%2C80627317%2C76615224%2C13521050%2C15247525%2C80160222%2C82220828%2C53436551%2C80131076&store_id=2315&zip=04333&state=ZE&latitude=51.510&longitude=3.610&required_store_id=2315&has_required_store_id=true&channel=WEB&page=%2Fc%2F5xu1e').json()
```

A simple way to circumvent the region permission issue would be to run this script on google colab.